# make an api between python to bring an excel from asana

Tags: python, asana

I need to bring data from asana to python, to later do data engineering. But the first one is getting complicated for me to bring the data, with requests, etc.

If anyone can help me thanks

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Show us the code you have, and tell us what isn't working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.